# ClassNotFoundException loading data from snowflake with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting this error when I try to load data from snowflake into a dataframe with pyspark:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/snowflake/client/jdbc/internal/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
```

Here is some code to reproduce the error:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars.packages',
         'net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.8.4-spark_2.4,net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.12.17')
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

sf_reader_options = {'sfURL': 'example.snowflakecomputing.com', 'sfAccount': 'example_account',
                     'sfWarehouse': 'example_warehouse', 'sfRole': 'DATASCIENCE', 'sfUser': 'user',
                     'sfPassword': 'pass', 'sfDatabase': 'db_name', 'sfSchema': 'schema_name', 'sfTimezone': 'UTC'}

reader = (spark
          .read
          .format('net.snowflake.spark.snowflake')
          .options(**sf_reader_options))

result = reader.option('query', 'select * from TABLE_NAME').load()
```

The stacktrace for the error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/charlie/lark/bigbird/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/Users/charlie/lark/bigbird/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/Users/charlie/lark/bigbird/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/charlie/lark/bigbird/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/snowflake/client/jdbc/internal/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Parameters$.mergeParameters(Parameters.scala:202)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 17 more
```

I am using spark 2.4.7 and spark-snowflake 2.8.4, with snowflake jdbc 3.12.17. I am on Mac OS X Big Sur. This happened after I upgraded to Big Sur, though I'm not sure whether that's related.

I have tried:

- adding bouncy castle provider to my configuration as a package dependency
- checking that `JAVA_HOME` points to Java 8 (it does)
- reinstalling java 8 (with homebrew and adoptopenjdk)
- adding bouncy castle as a security provider, per instructions [here](https://justrocketscience.com/post/install-bouncy-castle/)
- updating spark-snowflake and snowflake-jdbc (was using 2.7.0 and 3.12.3 before, same error)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your classpath seems to be broken. You should add the Bouncy Castle JAR to your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I was able to resolve this by:

- downloading Java straight from Oracle (rather than uninstalling and reinstalling with homebrew),
- deleting spark, downloading again (from apache, not via homebrew), and setting up environment variables as described [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-ubuntu) (mostly... I use a virtual environment so I didn't hardcode PYSPARK_PYTHON to system python3)
- uninstalling pyspark and reinstalling
- quitting pycharm and reopening (this refreshed all my environment variables that were set in .zshrc, like JAVA_HOME)

There's almost certainly an easier way, but this worked.